# Laravel functional testing ajax control

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In laravel 5.4, I can see that there are methods such as:

```
$browser->pause(1000);
$browser->waitFor('.selector');
$browser->waitForLink('Create');
```

But I don't see these in Laravel 5.3.

We have two chained select boxes where second select box values are loaded through ajax based on selection from first select box. The problem is that when we run test, laravel doesn't wait for second selectbox/ajax to load which makes the test fail because it could not select any value from second select box.

```
$this->visit('/department');
$this->select('1', 'country_id');
$this->select('1', 'region_id'); // problem here
// rest of code
```

I also tried using `sleep()` but it didn't work.

Any idea of how to functional test such scenario in 5.3 please ? Thanks

Comment: Thats why laravel 5.4 was needed as it wasn't in 5.3 improvement

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI: But there has to be a way in 5.3 to test such scenario i assume.

Comment: I found this package which can allow to use Laravek Dusk as standalone package: https://github.com/duncan3dc/dusk

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, laravel 5.3 doesn't support this function. As they have introduced Ajax Testing in laravel 5.4 using Dusk.

Check this post : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-dusk-is-coming

**However, We are in luck.**

Looking at the composer.json of dusk. You can use it in laravel 5.3 as its dependency is `"illuminate/support" : "~5.3"` which is satisfied by the Laravel 5.3.

All you need to do is : `composer require laravel/dusk`

Check the `composer.json` here : https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/master/composer.json

**Edit:**

There was an issue with the dependency. I created a new package which resolved the dependency issue. I have run all the test cases. It didn't give me any error.

You can use this package using following command : `composer require pankitgami/dusk`

Check here : https://packagist.org/packages/pankitgami/dusk

Comment: Cannot install dusk on 5.3. Error ` Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v3.1.9` and `Installation request for symfony/console (locked at v3.1.9) -> satisfiable by symfony/console[v3.1.9].`

Comment: awesome, it worked thanks :) Please don't remove this modified version from packagist as I will be using in my project :)

Comment: Yeah, I won't remove it. Plus I will keep on updating it.

Answer (score 0):

**seeJsonEquals** used for Verify Exact JSON Match

```
    $this->post('/user', ['name' => 'Sally'])
         ->seeJsonEquals([
             'created' => true,
         ]);
```